# Returning a reference to a Box<dyn Trait>

Tags: rust

Started learning rust this weekend, and I'm trying to write a little private helper method on my class to look up some internal values, but it's proving quite complicated. I have a few structs implementing a trait:

```rust
trait Animal {}

struct Dog {}
impl Dog for Animal{}

struct Cat{}
impl Cat for Animal{}
```

along with a container which holds multiple variants of animal:

```rust
struct Person {
  my_dog: Dog,
  my_cat: Cat
}
```

What I want to do is write a helper which looks up the appropriate Animal, like this:

```rust
impl Person {
  fn look_up_animal(&self, animal_name: &str) -> Box<&dyn Animal> {
    match animal_name {
      "dog" => Box::from(&self.my_dog),
      "cat" => Box::from(&self.my_cat)
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't quite figure out how to do the types for this. The version above using references **and** `Box` gives an error like "expected `struct Box<&dyn Animal>` but got `struct Box<&Dog>`, so I'm not really sure how to convert a regular value into a `dyn` value.

Comment: Not directly related to your question (but necessary to get a working solution), but what do you want to happen if `animal_name` is neither `"dog"` nor `"cat"`?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need the `Box` part of this here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fully explicit version of what you want would be

```rust
impl Person {
    fn look_up_animal(&self, animal_name: &str) -> Option<Box<&dyn Animal>> {
        match animal_name {
            "dog" => Some(Box::from(&self.my_dog as &dyn Animal)),
            "cat" => Some(Box::from(&self.my_cat as &dyn Animal)),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

Rust is able to coerce one layer of references to trait objects, but two layers of references (both `Box` and `&`) trips it up. (Having a reference inside a `Box` also triggers a `clippy` warning.) That suggests another solution.

```rust
impl Person {
    fn look_up_animal(&self, animal_name: &str) -> Option<&dyn Animal> {
        match animal_name {
            "dog" => Some(&self.my_dog as &dyn Animal),
            "cat" => Some(&self.my_cat as &dyn Animal),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

This time, the explicit cast `as &dyn Animal` is unnecessary since there's just a single layer of references.

```rust
impl Person {
    fn look_up_animal(&self, animal_name: &str) -> Option<&dyn Animal> {
        match animal_name {
            "dog" => Some(&self.my_dog),
            "cat" => Some(&self.my_cat),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

[(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=33af2b3ffd0774c936071ecdb87327a8)

---

Note: I added in the `Option` so that there's something to return when `animal_name` isn't `"dog"` or `"cat"`. You could also panic or default to something else that implements `Animal`.